# Query with RegExp and Array

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a class `Post`, with the following scope:

```
scope :by_tag, ->(tag){ where(:desc => /##{Regexp.escape(tag)}/) }
```

It works very well with one tags, but I can't make it work with various tags.

For example: I cant make it give me the posts tagged with #rails AND #regexp.

With criteria union I can make it return me the posts tagged with #rails OR #regexp.

How can I get it to work? I'm using mongoid, btw.

Thanks in advance.

---

Just fount that is not an OR. What happens is that the second time I call by_tag, it overrides the previous. I believe that's because it's the same property.

Someone know how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regexp queries tend to be really slow. Instead, store an array of tags and use `$in` to query the array.

With Mongoid 2.x use [`all_in`](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#all_in)

```
scope :by_tags, ->(*tags) { all_in(tags: *tags) }
```

With Mongoid 3 use [`all` merge strategy](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html#merging)

```
scope :by_tags, ->(*tags) { all(tags: *tags) }
```

Comment: very interesting. I'll try it at home tonight. Thank you very much!

Comment: by the way: I can pass a array of tags, and it will automatically find the items that contains all tags passed? Ex: `Post.by_tags '#mongo', '#rails'` will return me the item Post with desc= 'testing #mongo in #rails'? That easy?

Comment: No, the desc field must be stored as array. If you want to keep the desc field as string like it is, add a new field (e.g. tags) that you set when storing the desc that contains the list of tags extracted from the desc. Then, you'll be able to query it with `by_tags`

Comment: got that... I'll have to do that anyway to made my life a bit easier in other places of the app. thanks man, at night I give you some feedback.